# installing QODBC driver for linux

Tags: linux, qt, odbc

I am trying to install QODBC drivers on ubuntu 13.10 for Qt 5.0.2. I have followed the official documentation (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc) but am stuck at one of the steps. When I try to do

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/unixODBC/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/unixODBC/lib -lodbc"
```

it just shows me the help manual for qmake and does nothing.
So I tried to make an empty Makefile and then passed it as an argument

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/unixODBC/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/unixODBC/lib -lodbc" Makefile
```

when I try to "make" the generated Makefile, it shows the following errors:

```
Makefile:183: warning: overriding commands for target `Makefile'
Makefile:130: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Makefile'
make: Circular Makefile <- Makefile dependency dropped.
make: Circular Makefile <- Makefile dependency dropped.
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just managed to make the odbc driver installation. The main problem here seems to be that you are not including the "pro" target file.

Here all the steps are:

1. Go to odbc pluggin path. In my case: cd ~/Qt/5.3/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc
2. Run qmake including the target LIB paths and also the pro file:

   ~/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake -makefile  "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lodbc" odbc.pro
3. make and then sudo make install

I hope it will be usefull.
Regards,